# How to keep default icons from changing in top panel

Tags: release-freya

I am currently trying out different themes. I love the elementary OS's, default icons on the top bar and I was wondering how to keep themes from changing it to their own bulkier and uglier versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the theme you're going to use.

If the theme contains indicator icons, you can check that in the status/panel folder in the directory where you installed the theme (`/usr/share/icons/` or `~/.local/share/icons`)

If the theme does not contain any status/panel icons, open the `index.theme` using your default text editor and in the line `Inherits=anotherthemename` replace `anotherthemename` with `elementary`.

If the theme does have status/panel icons, you can delete those folders for all sizes and don't forget to remove the entries from `index.theme` too. If you have a theme like that `Directories=dir1, dir2` and you want to remove `dir2` you should look for something like

```
[dir2/16]
Size=*
Context=*
MinSize=*
MaxSize=*
Type=*
```

for all the sizes and remove them.

The last step is updating icon theme cache `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache -f /usr/share/icons/iconthemefolder` and change `iconthemefolder` with the folder name of theme you want to use.

Please create a backup of the theme before doing any modifications.